# Is the product of a diagonal matrix and a rank-$1$ matrix still rank-$1$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

First let me make two statements to give my question the proper context.

1. Consider $D$ a diagonal matrix and $u v^T$ a rank 1 matrix. 
   From my current knowledge there exist computationally cheap algorithms to diagonalize $D+uv^T$ as discussed here: [maximum eigenvalue of a diagonal plus rank-one matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506761/maximum-eigenvalue-of-a-diagonal-plus-rank-one-matrix)
2. Diagonalizing a matrix of the form $Duv^T$ is straightforward, see here: [Eigenvector of a diagonal matrix times a rank-1 matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580482/eigenvector-of-a-diagonal-matrix-times-a-rank-1-matrix)

Now to my question(s):

1. I want to diagonalize $D^2+Duv^T$. Is $Duv^T$ still a rank 1 matrix? I considered some examples but I am not really sure if this is a general statement.
2. This question depends on the answer of the first. If the statement is true the algorithms in statement 1 should be applicable to  diagonalization of $D^2+Duv^T$, no? If it is not true are there others ways to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=v=(1,0)^T$, and

$$D=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then

$$uv^T=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$$

And $Duv^T=0$.

Of course, if $D$ has only nonzero diagonal elements, then it has full rank and the product has rank $1$, see [matrix rank properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Properties) on Wikipedia. And if $Duv^T$ has not rank $1$, it's necessarily the null matrix, so it's not a very interesting case.

Comment: Ok thanks, so its actually very easy to write a proof from these properties...
let D be of full rank ($rank(D)=n$) and use sylvester rank inequality:
$1 = rank(uv^T) = rank(D)+rank(uv^T)-n \le rank(Duv^T) \le min(rank(D),rank(uv^T)) =1 $