# Eigenvector of a rank-$1$ matrix times a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements zero or one can we obtain a simple expression for the eigenvector and eigenvalue of $\mathbf a \mathbf a^T \mathbf{D}$? A similar problem is described in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580482/eigenvector-of-a-diagonal-matrix-times-a-rank-1-matrix) but didn't help me a lot.

Comment: Using the associative property as in the linked question, I think you'll find that $a$ is an eigenvector of $aa^TD$.

Comment: Now, you just notice that $\dim\ker aa^TD=n-1$, so the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ (multiplicity at least $n-1$) and $a^TDa$ (multiplicity at most $1$), with eigenspaces $\ker(aa^TD)$ and $\mathrm{Span}\{a\}$ (if the eigenvalues are different).